# Connecting MacBook to external monitor and peripheral devices used by a PC?

Tags: keyboard, display, mouse, pc

I have a MacBook Pro and a PC. I'm using both, but I'd love to be able to connect my MacBook Pro to my PC's keyboard, mouse and monitor.

Normally I have to go under the desk, take all the cables out then connect them to my Mac, and it's a pain to do.

I'm wondering if it's possible to make it easier somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your PC specs you may use a VGA or HDMI USB [KVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) (Keyboard, Video, Mouse) switch.
This will allow you to connect 2 or more computers to one screen, mouse and keyboard, and switch between them pressing a button.
The keyboard and mouse must be USB (wired or wireless) in this case, so they work on both computers.

There are plenty on Amazon and eBay.

On my experience, VGA KVMs have problems with screen resolution and offer a generally crappy viewing experience; I ordered an HDMI one and may update the answer based on its performance.